# GDB mi interpreter returns empty -symbol-info-functions

Tags: gdb

I'm using gdb 9.2 from the default repos on my Ubuntu20.04 .
I'm writing a simple front end that uses gdb for some tasks ,"Debugging binary files without debug symbols"
Gdb starts as -i=mi and works fine for most commands
Now I have a weird behavior from gdb as the the command -symbol-info-functions returns nothing , so I tried in CLI and it works fine , I'm aware that debug infos are stripped from my binaries so I need to run the
`-symbol-info-functions --include-nondebug`.

the problem that whenever I start gdb as a CLI , the commands

`info functions`

and

```
interpreter-exec mi "-symbol-info-functions --include-nondebug"
```

both of these works fine, returning the expected output.

When I start gdb with -i=mi
both
`-symbol-info-functions --include-nondebug` and

```
-interpreter-exec console "info functions"
```

returns empty ,

Is there something wrong with me or with gdb ??

[This picture may clarify the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Hu1.png)

Comment: Try `-file-exec-and-symbols` instead of `-file-exec-file`.

Comment: Thanks, this was it ,it wasn't that clear in the docs